# How to separate files in prolog

Tags: prolog

I wanna know if it´s possible to separate files in prolog, for example:
I wanna have my interface, rules, facts, consults in separate files and make them work together.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Look up the `include` directive.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - look at 'modules' in the SWI-Prolog documentation.

In short, you consult one file and it loads the others.  So, say you have a.pl, b.pl, and so on

here's `b.pl`

```
bear(X) :- write('I see a bear named '), writeln(X).
bull(X) :- write('I see a bull named '), writeln(X).
```

at top of `b.pl`

put

```
:- module(b, [bear/1]).
```

Now you can use bear (the `/1` means 'with one argument') outside this file.

in `a.pl` put

```
:- use_module(b).
```

Notice that there's no .pl on that

and then you can refer to bear

final program

#### a.pl

```
:- use_module(b).

go :-  bear('Yogi').
```

#### b.pl

```
:- module(b, [bear/1]).

bear(X) :- write('I see a bear named '), writeln(X).
bull(X) :- write('I see a bull named '), writeln(X).
```

This way you can make things like bull/1 private to a single module.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, yes. Long answer, depends on what you mean by "interface" and how simple or complex are your requirements. As mbratch pointed out, the ISO Prolog standard `include/1` directive can be used to include e.g. a set of predicate directives in files containing definitions for those predicates. If, on the other hand, your application requires multiple implementations of the same interface, you may be able to use Prolog modules together with the `include/1` directive where each module would provide an implementation depending on what you want as an interface or use Logtalk, which provides interfaces as a first class entity. A more sound advice and detailed answer, however, requires on you providing more information on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi Paulo when I said interface I´m talking about GUI using xpce. What I´m trying to do is simple, I don´t like the idea of keep everything in just one file(facts, rules, consults, gui), I wanna have the facts just in one file, rules in another file and so on, and I want to be able to access the facts in my rules or consults...